# WebMatrix ReCaptcha Helper

Tags: c#, .net, razor, captcha, webmatrix

I am currently using the WebMatrix ReCaptcha @Helper, though too many of them are unreadable.

Is there a way to have your *own* text appear in the captcha part?

I see there is the option on the recaptcha.net website, but there is no info available for the webmatrix helper that I can find.

Comment: Can you show me where you see that option on their site?  I can't find it in the docs anywhere.  AFIK it isn't possible to set your own text.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know recaptcha works with google books. Texts that the scanning algorithm can't read are handed to recaptcha, so real people will tell what the word is. I don't think that there is a way to add your own